# how to save data in separate file in google sheet in react natvie

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, google-sheets

I use the ***best sheet API*** to save the data into the Google sheet. it saves my data to Google Sheets but it duplicates data again and again. now I want to create a new file every time the user wants to save this data in a separate file in the same Google sheet. but I can not do this in the bedsheet API. so how can this with bestsheet API?

```
const url = 'https://sheet.best/api/sheets/69042d86-72ec-4c78-8400-67a9bd4cf766?fileName=`${fileName}`';

    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    };

    axios
        .post(url, formattedTrans, config)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Response ------------------------------------>>>', response);
            dispatch(changeLoadingStatus());
            if (response) openGoogleSheetsLink();
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(changeLoadingStatus());
            if (error.response) {
                console.log('Response Data:', error.response.data);
                Toast.show({
                    type: 'error',
                    text1: 'Server Error',
                    text2: 'Server Error Request failed!'
                });
            }
        });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cWG3.jpg)

let's see the above image my data is only saved in sheet 1 and duplicates many times. but I want to save data in separate files i.e. sheet1, sheet2, and so on. I want the sheets to be created while saving the data.